# Get DayName from Date in OpenOffice Calc?

Tags: openoffice-calc, date

I am having difficulty getting the day name from OpenOffice Calc. I am able to get the day Number representation from a date with the following

```
WEEKDAY("2008-06-14"; 1)
```

which returns

```
7
```

As we specified type = 1 in the weekday function, 7 = **Saturday**
I do not want a number to represent a day, I want the actual cell to show **Saturday** instead of **7**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Retagged as this does not appear to have anything to do with Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply format the cell to display the day name instead of an integer.

In the '*Format Cells*' dialogue box (right click and choose '*Format Cells...*' to open) enter:

```
NNNN
NNN
```

or

```
NN
```

in the '*Format code*' field near the bottom.

NNNN gives you the full name day, but follows the name with a comma (eg. Wednesday,).

NNN gives you the full name day, with no trailing punctuation (eg. Wednesday).

NN gives a contracted day name, and does not follow it with any punctuation (eg. Wed).

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to **display** day name and retain it's value - use user defined format of `NNN`.
If you want to actually change it to text - use `TEXT(WEEKDAY("2008-06-14"; 1);"NNN")`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by converting your result into a text. To do this you write:

```
=TEXT(7,"DDDD")
```

The output is:

```
Saturday
```

A solid alternative would be:

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY("2008-06-14", 1), "DDDD")
```

This leads to the same result.

Comment: Either of these functions do not work in openoffice calc, gives result Err:509

Answer (score 0):

If cell A1 contains a serial date number then `=TEXT(WEEKDAY(A1,1),"DDDD")` resolves to the name of the week day.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the other answers?